# ¿Como podría prohibir el acceso según el valor de la DB en páginas php?

Tags: php

Alguna manera no muy larga de prohibir el acceso a usuarios según rol o valor de alguna columna de db tal vez con session? tengo la columna userType númerica para la tabla de usuarios, y me gustaría prohibir el acceso a ciertos archivos php con 0 o 1, estoy usando algo temporal.

Mi código php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('includes/config.php');
error_reporting(0);
if(strlen($_SESSION['login'])==0)
  { 
header('location:index.php');
}
else{

// el html aqui

?>
<?php } ?>
```

Aquí mi solución temporal:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['utype']=='1'):?>

// página html

<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer una condición `if` para verificar si el `utype` que tiene el usuario es `0` o no. Si cumple, le muestra al usuario que no tiene acceso, de lo contrario, muestra tu código HTML, ejemplo:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('includes/config.php');
error_reporting(0);

if(strlen($_SESSION['login'])==0)
  { 
header('location:index.php');
}
else{
  if ($_SESSION['utype']==0) {
    echo "sin acceso."
  } else {
    // el html aqui
  }
?>
```

O también algo más reducido, donde indico que si ambos cumplen, te envían a la vista `index.php`, o también podrían mostrar algún mensaje de "sin acceso":

```
<?php
session_start();
include('includes/config.php');
error_reporting(0);

if(empty($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['utype']==0) {
  header('location:index.php');
} else {
  // el html aqui
}
?>
```

Comment: Después del `header` podrias hacer un `die();` o `exit;` y así ahorrarte el `else`.

Comment: @Marcos en el else tengo otro if con una funcción por eso esta así.

Comment: @Marcos Lose te entiendo, pero lo que yo me refiero es que en el else tengo otra función y el html va debajo, el código que he posteado esta así por no pegar tanto código a la pregunta, pero mi código es diferente, solo necesitaba saber como podría hacer lo que pregunto porque después lo adapto al código que tengo.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Es una buena opción de hacerlo, me gusta la primera opción con el echo mostrando error, aunque me da error 500 aun cerrando el echo que le faltaba ;

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Lose no la marqué aún porque no encuentro poque me da error 500 en tu respueta del echo por alguna razón.